# Remover comentários de HTML

Tags: java, regex

Tenho um `TXT` retirado de um arquivo HTML.

Ele está cheio de comentários que preciso remover e então pensei em usar o método `replaceAll` da classe `String`, fazendo o seguinte:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   FileReader ler = new FileReader("/home/adriano/Desktop/html.txt");
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(ler);  
   String arquivo = "";
   while( reader.readLine() != null ){
     arquivo += reader.readLine() + "\n";
   }
   System.out.println(arquivo.replaceAll("s/<!--(.|\\s)*?-->//g", ""));
}
```

Acontece que não removeu os comentários, alguém sabe me dizer se essa *regex* está correta?

Tenho comentários do tipo:

```
<!-- Assinatura principal -->
<!-- [if gte mso 9]><xml> <o:OfficeDocumentSettings> <o:AllowPNG /> </o:OfficeDocumentSettings> </xml><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Teste assim: `System.out.println(arquivo.replaceAll("<!--(.|\\s)*?-->", ""));`

Comment: @Sorack usando esse regex lançou a exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Comment: Na linha do `replaceAll`?

Comment: O `s/` e `//g` não fazem parte da regex em si. Essa sintaxe é usada em outras linguagens (e em alguns comandos, como o `sed`), mas no Java vc só passa a expressão: `replaceAll("<!--(.|\\s)*?-->", "")`. Se bem que, como a entrada é um HTML, talvez seja melhor usar libs específicas, como o [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/download), por exemplo. Regex pode até funcionar para alguns casos, mas [há casos especiais que não serão cobertos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5654032), e que uma lib especializada em HTML tratará mais facilmente. Por fim, link obrigatório: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454 :-)

Answer (score 1):

O `s/` e `//g` não fazem parte da regex em si. Essa sintaxe é usada em outras linguagens (e em alguns comandos, como o `sed`), mas no Java você só precisa passar a expressão regular como parâmetro:

```
replaceAll("<!--(.|\\s)*?-->", "")
```

De qualquer forma, esta expressão não é muito boa em termos de eficiência, e pode inclusive dar `StackOverflowError` [se usada em strings muito grandes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7510006) (como [parece ser o seu caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360486/remover-tag-de-coment%C3%A1rio-html-com-java#comment720338_360486)).

Basicamente, a [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (indicada por `|`) faz com que as duas alternativas sejam verificadas, caso necessário. Na maioria das vezes cairá no primeiro caso (o ponto, que significa "qualquer caractere", mas que por padrão, na verdade significa "qualquer caractere, exceto [quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)"). Toda vez que a regex encontrar uma quebra de linha, a alternância testará a primeira opção e depois a segunda. Além disso, o operador lazy (`*?`), apesar de conveniente para o seu caso, [também tem o seu preço](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_expensive). Para strings pequenas, esses detalhes não importam, mas para strings grandes começa a fazer diferença (e estou assumindo que seu arquivo é grande o suficiente para isso fazer diferença, já que você mencionou que deu `StackOverflowError`).

Você pode remover a alternância se fizer com que o ponto também corresponda a quebras de linha, usando a opção [`DOT_ALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL). No caso do método `replaceAll`, não é possível passar esta opção como parâmetro, mas você pode habilitá-la colocando `(?s)` no início da regex:

```
arquivo.replaceAll("(?s)<!--.*?-->", "");
```

Isso já deve melhorar um pouco o desempenho da regex. Fiz uma comparação no regex101.com, e veja que a [primeira versão](https://regex101.com/r/dapW65/4/debugger) precisa de mais passos para verificar a string, se comparado com a [segunda versão](https://regex101.com/r/qx0YPe/5/debugger).

**É claro** que esses números vão variar conforme as strings, já que cada linguagem possui uma *engine* com detalhes de implementação próprios, algumas otimizam alguns casos, etc. Mas de maneira geral, remover a alternância já aumenta bastante o desempenho. Como eu não tenho o seu arquivo completo e não consegui simular o `StackOverflowError`, estou me baseando nos testes do regex101.com (mas sugiro que faça testes com os arquivos de fato para ter certeza).

A outra vantagem é para os casos de terem comentários mal formados (faltando a tag de fechamento, por exemplo). Veja que a [primeira versão](https://regex101.com/r/dapW65/6/debugger) precisa de mais de 2700 passos para perceber que o comentário não tem fechamento, enquanto a [segunda versão](https://regex101.com/r/qx0YPe/7/debugger) precisa de apenas 140. Mesmo que o seu arquivo não tenha isso, o desempenho geral da segunda versão, se comparada com a primeira, já justifica a mudança.

---

#### Outra alternativa

Você ainda pode otimizar um pouco mais usando a regex abaixo:

```
arquivo.replaceAll("<!--(?>[^-<>]*)(?>(?!-->)[-<>][^-<>]*)*-->", "");
```

Ela usa uma técnica conhecida como [*Unrolling the Loop*](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=89547), e é descrita em mais detalhes [neste livro](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do). Mas basicamente ela consiste em identificar 3 elementos básicos do trecho que você quer capturar:

- os delimitadores: no nosso caso, são `<!--` e `-->`, que aparecem no início e fim da regex
- o "normal": ou seja, o que é mais frequente que apareça entre os delimitadores. No caso, eu usei `[^-<>]*` (zero ou mais caracteres que não sejam o hífen, `<` ou `>`)
- o "especial": o caractere que não é normal (mais frequente em um comentário) e/ou que pode significar que encontramos o delimitador final (no caso, usei `[-<>]` - um hífen, ou `<` ou `>`)

O formato geral da regex é `delim normal* (especial normal*)* delim`. Também são usados [grupos atômicos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) (indicados por `(?>`)), que fazem com que a engine não faça *backtracking* (isso acontece quando ela não encontra um *match*, mas volta alguns passos para tentar outras combinações da string, fazendo com que demore mais). Mas como o "normal" e "especial" são mutualmente exclusivos, o backtracking será feito à toa, então o grupo atômico pula esses passos desnecessários.

Eu também uso um [*lookahead* negativo](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (o trecho `(?!-->)`). Basicamente, este trecho verifica se algo não existe à frente (no caso, eu verifico se não há o fechamento do comentário `-->`). Se não tiver, a regex prossegue para o `[-<>]` (hífen ou `<` ou `>`), seguido de zero ou mais caracteres que não são hífens (e todo este trecho pode se repetir várias vezes, pois há outro `*` fora dos parênteses). Isso garante que possam existir hífens e até mesmo `<` ou `>` dentro do comentário (ex: `<!-- <!-- abc ->----->` é um único comentário).

[Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/40DzX6/7/debugger) que o desempenho melhora um pouco se comparado à segunda versão. Novamente, para strings pequenas, a diferença será irrelevante, mas para strings grandes - como parece ser o seu caso - pode fazer uma grande diferença.

---

#### Use um parser de HTML

Mas talvez regex [não seja a melhor solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) para o seu caso. Por que não usar um parser de HTML?

Fiz o exemplo abaixo com o [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) versão 1.8.3:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;


public void removerComentarios(Node node) {
    for (int i = 0; i < node.childNodeSize();) {
        Node child = node.childNode(i);
        if (child.nodeName().equals("#comment")) {
            child.remove();
        } else {
            removerComentarios(child);
            i++;
        }
    }
}


Document doc = Jsoup.parse(arquivo);
removerComentarios(doc);
System.out.println(doc.html());
```

Claro que ainda existe o problema do arquivo ser muito grande e poder estourar a memória, mas ainda sim me parece ser uma solução mais simples do que uma regex.
Se o jsoup não te atender, você pode escolher outro [desta lista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers).